# Looking at datastore field that is not indexed

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

I have an `id` field that is indexed and a boolean field `x` that is not indexed. Is there any way to view all the entities with x set to true *without* the following?

- having a set of ids to filter by
- scrolling through the UI page by page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. Cloud Datastore requires an index to query for a property. You could write a script to generate the list of IDs. For example, in python:

```
from google.cloud import datastore

client = datastore.Client()

query = client.query(kind='foo')
results = list(query.fetch())

for i in results:
    if i['x'] == True:
        print('Entity {} with id {} has x = True'.format(i.key, i['id']))
```